# Couldnt connect to Oracle Database using VB script

Tags: oracle, vbscript, connection, odbc, adodb

Hi Please help me with the following. I used the below VB code to upload a text file to my oracle database.When i run my script i have the error message "Class not defined ADODB"

```
Set Obj_DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog



Obj_DBConn.ConnectionString ="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
                             "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
                             "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
                             "(HOST=##test##)(PORT=##test##))" & _
                             "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=##test##))); " & _
                             "uid=test;pwd=test;"


Obj_DBConn.Open Database_Path


Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")




Set f = Nothing

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\test.txt", ForReading, True)

For i = 1 To 10000

v_Line_String = f.ReadLine


v_Output_Each_part = Split(v_Line_String,";",-1,1)

v_Col_A = v_Output_Each_part(0)
v_Col_B = v_Output_Each_part(1)
v_Col_C = v_Output_Each_part(2)



Obj_DBConn.Execute "INSERT INTO  test_me (ID_Q, NAME, ROLLNO) VALUES ('"       & v_Output_Each_part(0) & "','" & v_Output_Each_part(1) & "','" & v_Output_Each_part(2) & "')"



Next
```

Please provide ur insights Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
Set Obj_DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
```

is VBA, not VBScript. Use

```
Set Obj_DBConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

to get this line passed the interpreter.

If you promise to delete the evil "On Error Resume Next", you may obtain further inspiration from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/9212a04b-ae1d-4a7f-87ba-cfa336898565).

**Update:**

If you google for something like "80004005 odbc oracle" you'll find [this trouble shooter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255084/en-us) with detailed step by step instructions to deal with connectivity problems. Next stop probably should be [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle).

Comment: Thanks you, my error prompt doesnt stop ther.. i have the following error prompt CODE:80004005 ERROR:[Microsoft][ODBC driver for oracle][Oracle] Source:Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers